# drawing real time graph in matplotlib recursion error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to use the code below to dynamically draw a graph from a pandas dataframe. The issue is that the update_graph() line is giving errors (https://gist.github.com/ishikawa-rei/759d9063c3add40712cd5a16696f9532). If i comment out the line the code runs but nothing is displayed on the graph as would be expected. The data is taken from a csv file which has one row of data that updates when something changes and just comprises of values between -100 and 100, example below.

```
google ... amazon ... apple
77         50         -100
```

.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

objects = ("google","ibm","kaspersky","amazon","facebook","sony","microsoft","apple")

def update_graph():
    fig.clear()
    cols = ["google","ibm","kaspersky","amazon","facebook","sony","microsoft","apple"]
    df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/dmnte/PycharmProjects/sentiment_analysis/live_information.csv",header=None,  names=cols,encoding = "UTF-8",low_memory=False)
    y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
    performance = df.values.tolist()
    flat_list = [item for sublist in performance for item in sublist]
    plt.bar(y_pos, flat_list, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
    plt.ylabel('company sentiment (%)')
    plt.title('Real time company sentiment')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    win.after(20000, update_graph())

fig = plt.figure()
win = fig.canvas.manager.window
update_graph()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: the link has all the output but the final error is RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem with your code is that you do not pass a reference of the `update_graph` function to `win.after()` but the return value after the execution of `update_graph()`. What I want to say is: there is a difference between passing `update_graph` and `update_graph()` as a parameter.

Here is a working toy code, where I changed the data loading. You can plug in your own `get_data()` function in which you load your `.csv` file.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


objects = ("google","ibm","kaspersky","amazon","facebook","sony","microsoft","apple")

def get_data():
    return np.random.randint(1,100, len(objects))

def update_graph():
    fig.clear()
    y_pos=np.arange(len(objects))
    data=get_data()
    plt.bar(y_pos, data, align="center", alpha=0.5)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
    plt.ylabel("company sentiment (%)")
    plt.title("Real time company sentiment")
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.manager.window.after(100, update_graph)


fig = plt.figure()
win = fig.canvas.manager.window
win.after(100, update_graph)
plt.show()
```